# How do I repeat the layers of Slic3r for every 3 infill layers with different angles? (Might need some programming knowledge)

Tags: software, slic3r, infill

I'm working on developing alternative infill layers to print at different angles, using Slic3r. Using Slic3r's rectilinear infill, printing at **specific angles for 3 layers then repeat**.

I'm working towards finding the code in the source code where they alternate the layers and change it to alternate it for every 3 layers.

I know I will need some C++ knowledge to fiddle around with the Slic3r's source code, but if there is someone who can point me in the right direction I would gladly appreciate it!

Comment: It would be nice if there were a way to do this, or to specify NO angle changes.

Answer (score 1):

Slic3r is available [on Github](https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r).

I think the section you'd be looking for [is here](https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/blob/bc35063a57788a23381b9e789289c27110fe07b7/xs/src/libslic3r/Fill/Fill.cpp)

Comment: Yups! Thank you for the comment! I have found that by changing the out angle you can command the angle at your will (Of course in programming terms).